# Spring Boot MVC mapping

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have problem with my Spring project. I just started with Spring Boot and i try to make ez controller which redirect me to another web.

When i started my application and go to browser on

> localhost:8080/person

there is problem with mapping idk why

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHmDJ.png)

This is my structure 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGGUu.png)

PersonController

```
package Controller;

import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import Model.Person;

public class PersonController {

        @RequestMapping("/person")
        public String person(Model model)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setFirstName("John");
            p.setLastName("BonJovi");
            p.setAge(23);
            model.addAttribute("person", p);
            return "personview";
        }
}
```

Person Class

```
package Model;

public class Person {
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

}
```

And "Main"

```
package demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"demo","controller"})


public class EducationProjectApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EducationProjectApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a @Controller to the top of your PersonController

**Also** - just check, your `@ComponentScan({"demo","controller"})`

"controller" is not capitalized, but your package is declared "Controller"

Comment: Thank you, it also helped :)

Answer (score 0):

You must annotated your ***PersonController*** class as ***@RestController***.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Person WEB</title>
</head>
<body>
 First Name: <span th:text="${person.firstName}"></span>
 Last Name: <span th:text="${person.lastName}"></span>
 Age: <span th:text="${person.age}"></span>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: For this case when you trying to return a HTML the annotation must be only @Controller and you have to make sure the model correspond to jsp page.

Answer (score 0):

Like Rafael said you need to put annotations above PersonController class. @RestController if you want to build a REST controller, @Controller if you want to build normal website. Make sure you already configure your view resolver so it will return a jsp files.